# Database of Medical Assertions

Tags: human-biology, database, medicine

Can anyone point me toward a computationally-accessible database of medical assertions? I'm looking for something where each row in the database contains a single unit of knowledge. It could either be in some sort of structured format, or be in free text.

Comment: What an interesting idea for a database! Do these type of databases exist for other fields? I've never heard of something like that until now. I'd love to browse such a resource. Looking forward to answers!

Comment: @A.Kennard: they definitely exist for computationally-driven domains that are narrow in scope! For example, the Neuroinformatics community is actively creating knowledge bases of Neuroscience-related information, and the Bioinformatics community has been active here for some time. I don't know about clinical findings, though, which would be handy for some machine learning experiments I'd like to try!